# Getting the URL of the current site root in java

Tags: java, spring-mvc

If we use it in the page http://www.somedomain.com/somepage..?=blah&two=blah, only www.somedomain.com have to be returned. I tried using

```
request.getScheme().toString() + "://" + request.getRemoteHost()`
```

But its returning an IP address, which is of no use for me. Kindly advice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: (I am just guessing) what do you get with request.getServerName()

Comment: @lmmy you are accessing the page using the domain and not the ip address, right?

Comment: @fmodos yes, by using the domain name only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `getServerName()` method which returns current domain name.

```
getServerName()
```

Returns the host name of the server that received the request.

```
getRemoteHost()
```

Returns the fully qualified name of the client that sent the request.

Source : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html

Comment: I tried getServerName() and it returns ip address of web server.

Comment: @MADTerry please add the reference from where you got this info, for example in this case I am assuming you copied this from here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html

Comment: @fmodos Sorry for that.Next time i would.

Comment: @Immy Then have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407203/tomcat-getheaderhost-vs-getservername .GetServerName is usually value taken from CGI variable `SERVER_NAME`

Comment: @MADTerry Well I tried that also , but of no use as I ended up with Ip address again.

Comment: @Immy Have you verified `httpd passes the Host header provided by the client `. This is the issue your httpd is not passing original header sent by client

Comment: @MADTerry can you specify where I need to place "ProxyPreserveHost On" in my web servers httpd.conf file, inside which section? 
As I have less idea about servers , any help will be great.

Comment: `<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>`

an new directive.Read it here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost

Comment: @MADTerry Thanks for pointing out solution. Now my virtual host is like : 
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.somedomain.co.id
     ServerAlias www.somedomain.co.id
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html
     ErrorDocument 503 /_ui/welcometoSomeDomain.html
     ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
And then I tried accessing site as http://somedomain.co.id and is worked fine , this time I got domain name. But now I am unable to access the site as www.somedomain.co.id, its giving 500 page saying CMSsite not found.

Comment: @immy server configuration seems to be correct.You can check server error log to diagnose the problem.