# How do I get the real server name in jsp, not the proxy's name

Tags: java, apache, jsp, jboss, reverse-proxy

**I have following (simplified) setup.**

[image: Setup]

From the client I call `http://somedomain.com/my.jsp`
via the proxy it's forwarded to apache 1 or apache 2

In my jsp I want the `server1-domain.com` or `server2-domain.com` and not `somedomain.com`

`request.getServerName()` gives me `somedomain.com` in the header the 'Host' param is also `somedomain.com`

It seems similar but just the opposite to: [tomcat-getheaderhost-vs-getservername](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407203/tomcat-getheaderhost-vs-getservername)

But I cannot turn of 'ProxyPreserveHost' as I am not the only one on the cluster... Optimal solution is not having to change anything to the domaincontroller/loadbalancer/apaches

Can I get it via just a JSP method/param?

Comment: Have you tried X-Forwarded headers, like X-Forwarded-For or X-Forwarded-Host?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407203/tomcat-getheaderhost-vs-getservername

Comment: Nope don't have the X-Forwarded headers..  I'm going to try this now: 
`String hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();`. Looks promising in the the spring controller (tested locally). I'm still building and deploying on the clustered development environment..

Comment: @andrucz you linked to the same question I refer to in my question... :-)

Comment: My bad. I didn't read your question completely :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this:

`String hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();`